# Recompiling a simple Win32 C++ app for x64

Tags: winapi, 64-bit

I have a small C++ program for Win32, which has the following WinMain:

```
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
```

when trying to compile for x64, I get the following error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WinMain referenced in function __tmainCRTStartup
```

What steps must be taken to recompile a simple win32 app for x64?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Your linker is set to link the executable under the `CONSOLE` subsystem, thus it's looking for `main`, you'll need to set the subsystem to `WINDOWS`.

Answer (score 0):

No promises, but I suspect your problem might be fixed by changing "APIENTRY" to "WINAPI".  If this does fix it, the problem was a differing calling convention.

If not, I suspect you need to look at your compiler flags.